# Call function out of the main script in Node.js

Tags: node.js, function, command-line, timer

in my main script I started an timer which calls a function periodically. How can I call a Stop-Method from outside the running file?

```
    var myVar = setInterval(progress, 10000);

    function progress() {
    // do smth
    }

    function stopInterval() {
       clearInterval(myVar);
    }
```

How can i call stopInterval() if the script is running?

I exported the function in my main.js like this:

```
    module.exports.stopTimer = function() {
    console.log("Stop Timer");
    clearInterval(myVar);
};
```

and i created a separate file (stoptimer.js) with the following content:

```
    var main = require('./main.js');
    main.stopTimer();
```

Is this right so far? If yes, how can I execute the stoptimer.js? My command-line is blocked because the main.js script is running.

Comment: It's not clear where you got stuck here because the simple answer is that you call `stopInterval()` from whatever code you are running.  Are you having a specific problem doing that?  If this is in a separate node.js module, then you have to export the `stopInterval()` function so it can be imported in another module and used there.

Comment: No one can really answer this question without knowing what `progress` is actually doing, however, I can tell you if it's executing CPU-bound code then the answer is you can't.

Comment: What do you mean from outside the running file? JavaScript has one global space. If you define stopInterval like this, you can call it from other locations... Please be more specific as @jfriend00 stated.

Comment: @Ralph - Note, the node.js tag on the question.  This is probably a question about calling something from another module in node.js, but the question is not clear about that at all so that's just a guess.

Comment: A small explanation for you to understand my problem: In my main.js I started the infinite interval. When I run the script via cmd I must kill the node process to stop the timer. Is it possible to call the stop-Method?

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. Missed the nodejs tag there.

You should expose the startInterval, stopInterval to your main script (via module.exports) and once you are done and ready to exit you call the stopInterval from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `clearInterval()` inside of the interval function,

```
let shouldRun = true;

function shouldStop(){
 shouldRun = false;
}

function progress(){
    if(!shouldRun){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
let interval = setInterval(progress, 10000);

// call from other file or elsewhere
setTimeout(()=>{shouldStop()}, 1500);
```